# Struggling to integrate sklearn and pandas in simple Kaggle task

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use the sklearn_pandas module to extend the work I do in pandas and dip a toe into machine learning but I'm struggling with an error I don't really understand how to fix.

I was working through the following dataset on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/data-science-london-scikit-learn/data).

It's essentially an unheadered table (1000 rows, 40 features) with floating point values.

```
import pandas as pdfrom sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper, cross_val_score
path_train ="../kaggle/scikitlearn/train.csv"
path_labels ="../kaggle/scikitlearn/trainLabels.csv"
path_test = "../kaggle/scikitlearn/test.csv"

train = pd.read_csv(path_train, header=None)
labels = pd.read_csv(path_labels, header=None)
test = pd.read_csv(path_test, header=None)
mapper_train = DataFrameMapper([(list(train.columns),neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3))])
mapper_train
```

Output:

```
DataFrameMapper(features=[([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39], KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
       n_neighbors=3, p=2, weights='uniform'))])
```

So far so good. But then I try the fit

```
mapper_train.fit_transform(train, labels)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e3897d6db1b5> in <module>()
----> 1 mapper_train.fit_transform(train, labels)

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.pyc in fit_transform(self, X, y,     **fit_params)
    409         else:
    410             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 411             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    412 
    413 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn_pandas/__init__.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    116         for columns, transformer in self.features:
    117             if transformer is not None:
--> 118                 transformer.fit(self._get_col_subset(X, columns))
    119         return self
    120 

TypeError: fit() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`
```

What am I doing wrong? While the data in this case is all the same, I'm planning to work up a workflow for mixtures categorical, nominal and floating point features and sklearn_pandas seemed to be a logical fit.

Comment: Your second import is not correctly indented.  I would correct the code myself if the edit was long enough.

Comment: Cross-posted with http://stackoverflow.com/q/24583249/2954547

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of how to get pandas and sklearn to play nice

say you have 2 columns that are both strings and you wish to vectorize - but you have no idea which vectorization params will result in the best downstream performance.

create the vectorizer

```
to_vect = Pipeline([('vect',CountVectorizer(min_df =1,max_df=.9,ngram_range=(1,2),max_features=1000)),
                    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer())])
```

create the DataFrameMapper obj.

```
full_mapper = DataFrameMapper([
        ('col_name1', to_vect),
        ('col_name2',to_vect)
    ])
```

this is the full pipeline

```
full_pipeline  = Pipeline([('mapper',full_mapper),('clf', SGDClassifier(n_iter=15, warm_start=True))])
```

define the params you want the scan to consider

```
full_params = {'clf__alpha': [1e-2,1e-3,1e-4],
                   'clf__loss':['modified_huber','hinge'],
                   'clf__penalty':['l2','l1'],
                   'mapper__features':[[('col_name1',deepcopy(to_vect)),
                                        ('col_name2',deepcopy(to_vect))],
                                       [('col_name1',deepcopy(to_vect).set_params(vect__analyzer= 'char_wb')),
                                        ('col_name2',deepcopy(to_vect))]]}
```

Thats it! - note however that mapper_features are a single item in this dictionary - so use a for loop or itertools.product to generate a FLAT list of all to_vect options you wish to consider - but that is a separate task outside the scope of the question.

Go on to create the optimal classifier or whatever else your pipeline ends with

```
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(full_pipe, full_params, n_jobs=-1)
```

Answer (score 7):

I have never used `sklearn_pandas`, but from reading their source code, it looks like this is a bug on their side. If you look for [the function that is throwing the exception](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas/blob/master/sklearn_pandas/__init__.py), you can notice that they are discarding the `y` argument (it does not even survive until the docstring), and the inner `fit` function expects one argument more, which is probably `y`:

```
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    '''
    Fit a transformation from the pipeline

    X       the data to fit
    '''
    for columns, transformer in self.features:
        if transformer is not None:
            transformer.fit(self._get_col_subset(X, columns))
    return self
```

I would recommend that you open an issue in [their bug tracker](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas/issues).

**UPDATE**:

You can test this if you run your code from IPython. To summarize, if you use the `%pdb on` magic right before you run the problematic call, the exception is captured by the Python debugger, so you can play around a bit and see that calling the `fit` function with the label values `y[0]` does work  -- see the last line with the `pdb>` prompt. (The CSV files are downloaded from Kaggle, except for the largest one which is just a part of the real file).

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from sklearn import neighbors

In [3]: from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper, cross_val_score

In [4]: path_train ="train.csv"

In [5]: path_labels ="trainLabels.csv"

In [6]: path_test = "test.csv"

In [7]: train = pd.read_csv(path_train, header=None)

In [8]: labels = pd.read_csv(path_labels, header=None)

In [9]: test = pd.read_csv(path_test, header=None)

In [10]: mapper_train = DataFrameMapper([(list(train.columns),neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3))])

In [13]: %pdb on

In [14]: mapper_train.fit_transform(train, labels)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-e3897d6db1b5> in <module>()
----> 1 mapper_train.fit_transform(train, labels)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.pyc in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    409         else:
    410             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 411             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    412
    413

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn_pandas/__init__.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    116         for columns, transformer in self.features:
    117             if transformer is not None:
--> 118                 transformer.fit(self._get_col_subset(X, columns))
    119         return self
    120

TypeError: fit() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn_pandas/__init__.py(118)fit()
    117             if transformer is not None:
--> 118                 transformer.fit(self._get_col_subset(X, columns))
    119         return self

ipdb> l
    113
    114         X       the data to fit
    115         '''
    116         for columns, transformer in self.features:
    117             if transformer is not None:
--> 118                 transformer.fit(self._get_col_subset(X, columns))
    119         return self
    120
    121
    122     def transform(self, X):
    123         '''
ipdb> transformer.fit(self._get_col_subset(X, columns), y[0])
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           n_neighbors=3, p=2, weights='uniform')
```

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't have known what had caused it. I only know most of the time it's my work that's at fault :)

Comment: @elksie5000 : I have added how to debug the call. I hope the last call is what you would expect from a successful call to the function (?). Otherwise, it is always good to know how to step into the code with `pdb` :)

Comment: I must admit pdb was something I was looking at again after working through the Python for Data Analysis book by Wes McKinney. I already work in IPython, but had been reasonably happy with print statements. Thank you again.

Comment: As a side note, the debugger prompt says "ipdb" because it is the ipython debugger - this is an extra install in my setup. Under normal circumstances, it would be the regular pdb that is called. Just noticed this difference.